# Spring boot cxf not work well in tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, wsdl

While I used Spring Boot cxf in my Project,I can access wsdl in Application main lunched way,but I can't access the wsdl in tomcat publish.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

WSDL:http://localhost:8080/service/gateWay?wsdl

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/tomcat-context/service/gateWay?wsdl where tomcat-context is context where application is deployed, usualy a war name.

Comment: thanks MGorgon,it work well as your said added the war name .